# Get all records from Table A and all entries that don't already exist from Table B

Tags: sql, oracle, group-by, left-join, inner-join

I have an Oracle DB with 2 tables, Table A and Table B.

Table A has better data quality but only for a limited set of entries. Table A has also multiple entries (because of history) and I only need the last one per number.

So I need to get all entries from Table A and then the rest of the entries which are not in Table A from Table B.

I also need to get some data from Table B into the result of Table A because the info does not exist in Table A (val1, val2, val3).

So probably some sort of JOIN + GROUP BY?

Table A:

```
number | valid_from | valid_to   | pos1 | pos2 | pos3 | factor | loc
100    | 2020-03-01 | 2020-03-10 | 7    | 80   | 18   | 19     | 1
100    | 2020-03-10 | 2020-03-13 | 7    | 80   | 18   | 19     | 1
100    | 2020-03-13 | 2020-03-16 | 8    | 80   | 18   | 20     | 1
200    | 2020-03-02 | 2020-03-03 | 6    | 90   | 19   | 30     | 1
200    | 2020-03-03 | 2020-03-04 | 6    | 90   | 19   | 29     | 1
200    | 2020-03-04 | 2020-03-10 | 9    | 90   | 19   | 30     | 1
300    | 2020-03-10 | 2020-03-12 | 13   | 100  | 10   | 41     | 2
300    | 2020-03-12 | 2020-03-14 | 13   | 100  | 10   | 40     | 2
300    | 2020-03-14 | 2020-03-20 | 10   | 100  | 10   | 40     | 2
```

Table B:

```
number | pos1 | pos2 | pos3 | val1 | val2 | val3 | top
100    | 7    | 70   | 18   | a    | aa   | aaa  | 3  
200    | 6    | 60   | 19   | b    | bb   | bbb  | 4
300    | 5    | 50   | 10   | c    | cc   | ccc  | 5
400    | 2    | 20   | 2    | d    | dd   | ddd  | 16
500    | 3    | 30   | 3    | e    | ee   | eee  | 28
```

End result should be:

```
number | pos1 | pos2 | pos3 | factor | loc  | val1 | val2 | val3 | top
100    | 8    | 80   | 18   | 20     | 1    | a    | aa   | aaa  | 3
200    | 9    | 90   | 19   | 30     | 1    | b    | bb   | bbb  | 4
300    | 10   | 100  | 10   | 40     | 2    | c    | cc   | ccc  | 5
400    | 2    | 20   | 2    | NULL   | NULL | d    | dd   | ddd  | 16
500    | 3    | 30   | 3    | NULL   | NULL | e    | ee   | eee  | 28
```

How can I achieve this? Do I need a FULL LEFT JOIN and GROUP BY by number? Not sure what to take or how to get the latest entries from Table A.

Answer (score 0):

```
select b.number, b.pos1, b.pos2, b.pos3, 
   a.factor, a.loc, b.val1, b.val2, b.val3, b.top  
from tableb b
left outer join tablea a
   on b.number = a.number
```

you can also use `NVL(b.pos1, a.pos1)`  which means if `b.pos1` is null take `a.pos1`

Answer (score 0):

I would write this as a `left join` with filtering:

```
select b.number, b.pos1, b.pos2, b.pos3, 
    a.factor, a.loc, 
    b.val1, b.val2, b.val3, b.top
from b
left join (
    select a.*, row_number() over(partition by number order by valid_from desc) rn
    from a
) a on a.number = b.number and a.rn = 1
```